# Bundler could not find the passenger gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

```
Rails 5.1
Ruby 2.4
Ubuntu 16.04
Passenger 5.1.8
```

My Gemfile does NOT have a passenger gem

My apache2 virtual host config file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin  admin@myapp.com
    ServerName  myapp.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/utils/rails/public"
    PassengerRuby /home/utils/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/wrappers/ruby
    PassengerAppEnv production
    PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on
    <Directory "/home/utils/rails/public">
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/follower_wonk_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/follower_wonk_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


ls -l /home/utils/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/wrappers/ruby
```

gives me:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 utils utils 274 Oct 11 14:50 /home/utils/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/wrappers/ruby
```

and  mods-available/passenger.conf has in it:

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
  PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/passenger_free_ruby
</IfModule>
```

But, when I do

```
curl http://myapp.com
```

I get an exception. I copied the extended error html file, and this is part of it:

```
-------- The exception is as follows: -------

Could not find passenger-5.1.8 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  /home/utils/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize'
  /home/utils/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `map!'
  /home/utils/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `materialize'
  /home/utils/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs'
  /home/utils/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:218:in `specs_for'
  /home/utils/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:207:in `requested_specs'
  /home/utils/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:109:in `block in definition_method'
  /home/utils/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:21:in `setup'
  /home/utils/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
  /home/utils/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/utils/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /home/utils/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

But passenger 5.1.18 is there.

I also ran:

```
rvmsudo passenger-config validate-install
```

and I got:

```
Everything looks good. :-)
```

for both passenger and apache

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the require bit in your Gemfile if you are using apache, that's for using `rails server`. https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/dev/ruby/rails_integration.html#rails-server-integration

Comment: So, then then the PassengerRuby /home/utils/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/wrappers/ruby directive in the apache config file is not needed either?

Comment: Yes that is needed. That tells passenger which ruby interpreter to use. The `, require: "phusion_passenger/rack_handler"` injects passenger integration into the `rails server` command. They are completely unrelated as `PassengerRuby` is an apache config and the `require` starts passenger standalone.

Comment: OK, I lost you. I am not using require anywhere

Comment: You say in the question that you are using it in your Gemfile.

Comment: Did you update your `gemfile.lock` too? Bundler is still looking for passenger so it has to be told to do that somewhere.

Comment: Synchronization error. The Gemfile did not synchronize properly from the source code tree, so I forced it manually, deleted Gemfile.lock and re installed gems. It works now